# Parametrizing a 3D surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

Find a parametrization of the surface $x^3 + 3xy + z^2 = 2$, $z > 0$, and use it to find the tangent plane at $x = 1$, $y = \dfrac{1}{3}$, $z = 0$.

I know how to find the tangent plane once I have the parametrization - it's the first part that's troubling me. I started by solving for $z$, which gave me the parametrization $(u, \, v, \, \sqrt{2-u^3-3uv})$. Then the partial derivative w.r.t. $u$ is $\left( 1, \, 0, \, \dfrac{-3(u^2+v)}{2 \sqrt{2-u^3 - 3uv}} \right)$. But when I plug in $u = 1$ and $y = \dfrac{1}{3}$, I get a discontinuity.

Not really sure what else to try. Maybe cylindrical coordinates would work better?

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to work without a parametrization. The gradient of a implicitly given surface is the normal of the tangent plane, no need for parametrization.

The gradient becomes

$$(3x^2+3y,3x,2z)=(4,3,0)$$

which gives you the normal.

Your parametrization is bad, because there are two branches of the square root and you are located precisely at $z=0$, where the branches meet. If you really want to use parametrization, select a different pair of variables. Or, you can multiply your entire divergent derivative vector by the square root in the denominator. Scaling doesn't matter if you only need directions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try this parametrization: $x = u$, $z = v$, and $y = (2 - v^2 - u^3)/3u$.